# Trigonometric problem: Elevation angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

The elevation of the top of a tower $KT$ from a point $A$ is $27^\circ$. At another point $B$, $50$ meters nearer to the foot of the tower where $ABK$ is a straight line, the angle of elevation is $40^\circ$. Find the height of the tower $KT$.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I did, I'm just very confused if I'm doing the steps right so I'm asking others on their responses. I gave up.

Comment: @shadow,he didn't ask **whether** you tried but **what** you tried.We don't really care if you confused the steps so long as you tried earnestly.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that. The answer looks close to what I did except for a few minor mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following diagram:
[image]

Looking at the **outer** (right-angled) triangle ($TAK$), and using trigonometry, we have:
$$(1) \tan(27)=\frac{h}{50+x}.$$

Looking at the **inner** (right-angled) triangle ($TBK$), and using trigonometry, we have:
$$(2) \tan(40)=\frac{h}{x}.$$

Now we've got a pair of simultaneous equations, $(1)$ and $(2)$. Solve them!
Also bear in mind that $\tan(27)$ and $\tan(40)$ are just numbers which you can find on a calculator.

Comment: nice drawing ! {} }{}

Comment: As you can probably tell, art was definitely my backup option, had I not gone into maths.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a right angled triangle $\;\Delta AKT\;,\;\;\angle K=90^\circ\;,\;\;\angle A=27^\circ$

We also have the right angled triangle $\;\Delta BKT\;\;\;\angle KBT=40^\circ\;,\;AB=50$

If we put $\;AK=x\;$, then $\;BJ=x-50\;$ , so by trigonometry:

$$\begin{align*}\text{On}\;\;\Delta AKT:&\;\;\tan 27^\circ=\frac{KT}x\\{}\\\text{On}\;\;\Delta BKT:&\;\;\tan40^\circ=\frac{KT}{x-50}\end{align*}$$

use now both those non-linear equations in $\;x\,,\;KT\;$ to find $\;KT\;$ (and you can find $\;x\;$ as well if you want to)

Comment: How is it sin and not tan?

Comment: Hehe...because I confused myself without a drawing: of course it is the tangent function. Thanks, editing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AK=d$, $BK=d-50$, and $KT=h$. Then
$$
\tan 27^\circ=\frac{h}{d}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad d=\frac{h}{\tan 27^\circ}\tag1
$$
and
$$
\tan 40^\circ=\frac{h}{d-50}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad d-50=\frac{h}{\tan 40^\circ}\tag2
$$
Substitute $(1)$ to $(2)$, yield
\begin{align}
\frac{h}{\tan 27^\circ}-50&=\frac{h}{\tan 40^\circ}\\
\frac{h}{\tan 27^\circ}-\frac{h}{\tan 40^\circ}&=50\\
h\left(\frac{1}{\tan 27^\circ}-\frac{1}{\tan 40^\circ}\right)&=50\\
h\left(\frac{\tan 40^\circ-\tan 27^\circ}{\tan 27^\circ\tan 40^\circ}\right)&=50\\
h&=50\left(\frac{\tan 27^\circ\tan 40^\circ}{\tan 40^\circ-\tan 27^\circ}\right)
\end{align}